# Shiny NotificationDelegate OnReceived not being called on iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms

We've been using [Shiny framework](https://github.com/shinyorg/shiny) for Local Notifications and it has done what we needed which is make a notification  appear on iOS and Android that when tapped will open the app.

However the OnReceived method on the INotificationDelegate never gets called on iOS. This has been the case forever IIRC but was of no real concern as we didn't need to do anything with the OnReceived except track it in AppCenter. Therefore fixing it never got prioritised.

Recently we have been looking at using Push Notifications. We are not using Shiny's push and instead are registering the device using out our own backend WebApi.

I am seeing a problem where our AppDelegate override of `ReceivedRemoteNotification` does not get called if i call the `UseNotifications` extension in our `ShinyStartup ConfigureServices`. We want to continue using Shiny for Local Notifications so this is a problem.

I am wondering if the issue that means our local notification received delegate does not get called is related to this issue.

Answer (score 3):

You are using ReceivedRemoteNotification which is for the "old" way of catching remote notifications in the foreground. Shiny.Notifications uses a UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate which I believe intercepts and stops that method. You can implement the Shiny notification delegate to work with the notification or use Shiny.Push.AzureNotificationHubs.

You can also use: DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action completionHandler) which is a better method to handle remote notifications anyhow since it is needed for background processing

Comment: I have implmented INotificationDelegate as we were already using it for LocalNotifcations howver we have had a long standing issue with OnReceived never being called on iOS only on Android. OnEntry works as expected on both platforms

Comment: Did you try any of the other suggestions that I made such as using DidReceiveRemoteNotification instead?  You're not really helping me help you here.  Please provide some sort of reproducible sample on github.  Note that the shiny samples uses both notifications and push mechanics with both working fine.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a 1 person team and was dragged off onto something else yesterday. I did implement DidReceiveRemoteNotification on our AppDelegate and it was not getting called either. tbh I am leaning towards using Shiny for both Push and Local. Seems foolish to roll my own implemenation of the local code just so I can do the device registration in a WebApi. I will try and get a sample together on Monday